# Retrofit | Parsing nested JSON objects ("Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at...)

Tags: android, json, rest, retrofit

I'm trying to parse this JSON into a POJO, but I'm getting an error

> "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2"

I believe that the problem is caused because I have nested JSON objects and json arrays. Here's what the JSON I'm trying to parse looks like:

```
[
   {
      "id":"3",
      "table":{
         "id":"1",
         "number":"1",
         "seats":"2",
         "description":"Vereda"
      },
      "user_id":"1",
      "status":null,
      "created_at":{
         "date":"2014-05-21 20:46:36",
         "timezone_type":3,
         "timezone":"UTC"
      },
      "updated_at":{
         "date":"2014-05-21 20:46:36",
         "timezone_type":3,
         "timezone":"UTC"
      },
      "items":[
         {
            "id":"1",
            "description":"",
            "name":"Caf\u00e9 mediano",
            "price":"8.5"
         },
         {
            "id":"1",
            "description":"",
            "name":"Caf\u00e9 mediano",
            "price":"8.5"
         },
         {
            "id":"1",
            "description":"",
            "name":"Caf\u00e9 mediano",
            "price":"8.5"
         },
         {
            "id":"1",
            "description":"",
            "name":"Caf\u00e9 mediano",
            "price":"8.5"
         },
         {
            "id":"1",
            "description":"",
            "name":"Caf\u00e9 mediano",
            "price":"8.5"
         },
         {
            "id":"2",
            "description":"dulce",
            "name":"Medialuna",
            "price":"3.75"
         },
         {
            "id":"2",
            "description":"dulce",
            "name":"Medialuna",
            "price":"3.75"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"5",
      "table":{
         "id":"2",
         "number":"2",
         "seats":"4",
         "description":"Mesa grande"
      },
      "user_id":"1",
      "status":null,
      "created_at":{
         "date":"2014-05-21 20:49:21",
         "timezone_type":3,
         "timezone":"UTC"
      },
      "updated_at":{
         "date":"2014-05-21 20:49:21",
         "timezone_type":3,
         "timezone":"UTC"
      },
      "items":[
         {
            "id":"1",
            "description":"",
            "name":"Caf\u00e9 mediano",
            "price":"8.5"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"6",
      "table":{
         "id":"5",
         "number":"5",
         "seats":"2",
         "description":null
      },
      "user_id":"1",
      "status":null,
      "created_at":{
         "date":"2014-05-21 20:51:12",
         "timezone_type":3,
         "timezone":"UTC"
      },
      "updated_at":{
         "date":"2014-05-21 20:51:12",
         "timezone_type":3,
         "timezone":"UTC"
      },
      "items":[
         {
            "id":"1",
            "description":"",
            "name":"Caf\u00e9 mediano",
            "price":"8.5"
         },
         {
            "id":"2",
            "description":"dulce",
            "name":"Medialuna",
            "price":"3.75"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"7",
      "table":{
         "id":"1",
         "number":"1",
         "seats":"2",
         "description":"Vereda"
      },
      "user_id":"1",
      "status":null,
      "created_at":{
         "date":"2014-05-22 02:09:30",
         "timezone_type":3,
         "timezone":"UTC"
      },
      "updated_at":{
         "date":"2014-05-22 02:09:30",
         "timezone_type":3,
         "timezone":"UTC"
      },
      "items":[

      ]
   }
]
```

As you can see, each object "ORDER" has nested objects like "Item" "Table" etc. Here are my respective Java Classes

**Order.class**

```
public class Order {

    private int id;
    private Table table;
    private int user_id;
    private Date created_at;
    private Date updated_at;

    //GETTERS AND SETTERS....

}
```

**Table.class**

```
public class Table {

    private int id;
    private String description;
    private int seats;
    private int number;

    //GETTERS AND SETTERS...    

}
```

**Item.class**

```
public class Item {


    private int id;
    private String description;
    private String name;
    private double price;

   //GETTERS AND SETTERS...
}
```

**Date.class**

```
public class Date {

    private String date;
    private int timezone_type;
    private String UTC; //GETTERS AND SETTERS...
}
```

I'm calling a retrofit through an interface like this:

```
@GET(Constants.URL_ORDERS)
public List<Order> retreiveOrders();
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was an ERROR specific to my application, my Android APP wasn't keeping my session alive so I was receiving an Object [action = "doSomething", status= "failure", message ="unauthenticated"]. My advice is: make sure your server side app works in a browser before you deploy it on android